# Aligning two wav files precisely

Tags: matlab, audio, wav, waveform

I have a tool which compares two audio wav files frame by frame and returns a grade which gives the level of similarity between the two files.

I have an original wav file and a recording of the wav file, since the two files are almost similar i should get a high score of similarity, yet i get a poor score, mainly due to a very slight delay in the recorded file-leading to frame mismatch

My question is- how do i go about aligning the two audio files exactly using MATLAB, so that a valid frame to frame comparison may be done.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should run a series of comparisons, shifting one of the frame in time and calculating the correlation between two. Highest value of correlation will give you time shift between waves.

I think you can use `xcorr` to achieve this.

Comment: i read both the files using x=wavread(firstfile) and y=wavread(secondfile). xcorr(x,y) gave an out of memory error. how do i rectify that?

Comment: Try wavread(firstfile, N) and the same for second file. N is the number of samples from the beginning of the wave. This will reduce the amount of memory needed. Pick N according to wave file length.

Comment: If this is too slow, you can use an FFT method to calculate the cross-correlation.

Answer (score 1):

Having had the same problem and without success to find a simple tool to sync the start of video/audio recordings automatically,
I decided to make [syncstart](https://pypi.org/project/syncstart/) ([github](https://github.com/rpuntaie/syncstart)).

It is a python-based command line tool that calculates the cut needed to bring the recordings into sync.

It uses an fft-based correlation of the start.

The basic code should be easily convertible to matlab:

```py
corr = fft.ifft(fft.fft(s1pad)*np.conj(fft.fft(s2pad)))
ca = np.absolute(corr)
xmax = np.argmax(ca)
if xmax > padsize // 2:
    offset = (padsize-xmax)/fs
    #second signal (s2) to cut
else:
    offset = xmax/fs
    #first signal (s1) to cut
```